# Angular HTML Forms - value attribute not working in input field

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-forms

I have a template-driven form in MyFormComponent template

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="employee">
<h3>Employee {{employee.lastname}}</h3>
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(f)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">Name </label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" ngModel value="{{employee.firstname}}" >
    </div>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Update Employee Name</button>
</form>
```

The goal of the form is to update the name of a given employee.\

And the .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../employee';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myform',
  templateUrl: './myform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myform.component.css']
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public myvar = "hi";
    constructor() {}

employee?: Employee;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployee();
}

submit(f: any){
  //Everything here works correctly. I do get the form object
}

getEmployee(): void {
  //Everything here works correctly
}
}
```

My problem is that the 'value' field is not showing in the app. It's blank/empty.
If instead of 'value' I use 'placeholder', it works. But I want it to be a default value there, so that the user doesn't have to type in if he does not want to change it.
If instead of {{employee.firstname}} I use 'myvar' which I declare public in the .ts file, it also does not show.

FormsModule is imported in root module.
@angular/cli 14.0.2. Mozilla/Chrome

Comment: Did yu try in your input [value]='employee.firstname' ?

Comment: Yes, doing so throws the error 'Parser Error: got interpolation ( {{ }} ) where expression was expected. What's the difference between value and [value]?
Doing [value]=mivar1 does not work, which shows the problem is somewhere else

Comment: It seems that your "employee" variable isn't initialized. Can you try something like employee?: Employee = { firstname: 'Roger' } and see what happens?

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because the <h3> tag works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with given 2 approach.

1.

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(f)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">Name </label><br />
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      name="firstname"
      [(ngModel)]="employee.firstname"
    />
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Update Employee Name</button>
</form>
```

2. 

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(f)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">Name </label><br />
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      name="firstname"
      [value]="employee.firstname"
    />
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Update Employee Name</button>
</form>
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-wind-1om7xp)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is delete ***ngIf="employee"** in the top level div and use **value="{{employee?.firstname}}"** instead.

So:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Employee {{employee?.lastname}}</h3>
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(f)">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstname">Name </label><br>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" ngModel value="{{employee?.firstname}}" >
      </div>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Update Employee Name</button>
  </form>
 .
 .
```

Comment: That works, thank you! Could you please explain what's happening, why 'value' field does not work inside *ngIf ?

Comment: It relates to the detection strategy and zone.js, you should avoid when you are using ngIf and have some Id or any form type in inner content. instead of ngIf you can use [hidden]="condition". for more detail see this [link](https://blogs.halodoc.io/understanding-angular-change-detection-strategy/)

Comment: Here's the answer to the why
https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#data-binding